# Getting violations on lightningChart

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

Please find attached screenshot showing violations that I am getting on using lightning chart line chart. I am not sure what is causing those violations. Is there a way to find what might be causing those violations.

Thanks[image: Violations]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of those "violations" are coming from LightningChart JS.

1. Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event.

   - We need to do this as we use the mouse wheel for user interactions and there are cases where we will block the scroll event. We will block the wheel event when there is a user interaction that results in an action on the chart. In any other case we will let the event do the default action.
2. 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took <N>ms

   - This is expected during the start up of our charts as there are some actions that will take longer than the ~16ms that is allocated for a single animation frame. This warning should only be triggered for a few frames during the start up. It can also be triggered when the hardware is no longer able to render new frames in that ~16ms time budjet. This mainly happens with large charts with a lot of data or on lower end devices.

There isn't anything that you can do to remove those two warnings. The other warnings look like are coming from either your framework or application.